# To use "are" or not?

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence, should "*are designed*" be just "*designed*", and if so why?

> Our products are focused on the educational setting and are designed to work ...

To me, removing it makes the sentence read better.

Comment: What products on earth are not designed to work? Your sentence sounds weird unless you specify the purpose of the design.

Comment: Apologies, I should have added an ellipsis at the end of the sentence to indicate that it continued.

Comment: @Rathony you have obviously not seen certain designs by software architects where I work :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the hiccup is the presentation of the two functions of the products: focus and design. To me this sentence feels like focus and design are separate ideas and the sentence as presented is correct. If you remove "are" before "designed" the design could be misinterpreted as part of the focus. Keeping "are designed" helps separate the design from the focus. Or you could add "they" before "are designed" to refer back to the product.